# Python regex not working as expected

Tags: python, regex

Why does the following python regex not generate `@Summary\n`?

```
import re
re.sub('$~ ','@','~ Summary\n')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` means "the position at the end of the string".

You need to use a different anchor for "the position at the start of the string":

```
re.sub(r'^~ ','@','~ Summary\n')
```

Comment: You sure you don't mean replace it with `^`?

Comment: And maybe, say `re.sub(r'\$~ ','@','$~ Summary\n')` instead!  (in order to get the _expected result_)

Comment: @user2357112 Looking at the __input__, it seems that you're right.

Comment: @user2357112: Of course, yes. Strange that I got upvotes for the previous version of this answer :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/515/the-problem-with-reputation-does-high-reputation-attract-too-many-upvotes

Comment: @devnull: And that is why I always teach my students to be skeptical of what authority figures say, including myself :)